# Is a space of uniformly bounded measures metrizable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $S$ be a Polish Space and  let $L$ denote the set of finite measures over $(S,\mathcal B(S))$ endowed with the weak topology (i.e.  the coarsest topology that makes
$\int g(s)\hat \sigma (ds)$ continuous for every continuous and bounded function $g$).

Let $\hat {\mathcal L}=\{\hat \sigma\in L|  \hat \sigma(S)\leq M\}$, for a fixed $M>0$.

It is known that the space of probability measures, which is a subset of $\hat {\mathcal L}$, is Polish. Is $\hat {\mathcal L}$ a Polish space as well?

Comment: Does this follow from the weak *-topology is in general not metrizable?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what I mean by the weak topology.

Comment: I see the problem, the set of finite measures is not the full dual space of $C_b(S)$.

Comment: Could you show that $\hat{\mathcal L} - \{0 \}$ is homeomorphic to the product of $(0, M]$ and the space of probabilities by normalizing $\hat{\mathcal L}$?

Comment: @Justauser that sounds interesting. Want to write a response?

Comment: Done. But I'm not 100% sure about the last step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map $\rho: \hat{\mathcal L} - \{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb P(S)\times (0, M]$, defined by $\rho(m) = (\frac{m}{m(S)}, m(S))$, which is clearly a continuous bijection.  To show it's a homeomorphism, we only need to show for any $g(s)\in C_b(S)$, the induced map on $\mathbb P(S)\times (0, M]$ is continuous. This also becomes clear once we recognize the map is just $(ds, x)\rightarrow x \int g(s)ds$.

Therefore as a product of Polish spaces, $\hat{\mathcal L} - \{0\}$ is Polish as well. To add $\{0\}$ into the space, note that $\{0\}$ is the strong limit of $\mathbb P(S)\times (0, \epsilon)$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, hence the weak limit as well. From here, it shouldn't be hard to show $\hat{\mathcal L}$ is Polish as well.